# Store multiple values in single key in json

Tags: arrays, json

I need to store many values in single key of json. e.g.

```
{
  "number" : "1","2","3",
  "alphabet" : "a", "b", "c"
}
```

Something like this. Any pointers?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Use arrays:

```
{
    "number": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "alphabet": ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```

You can the access the different values from their position in the array. Counting starts at left of array at 0. `myJsonObject["number"][0] == 1` or `myJsonObject["alphabet"][2] == 'c'`

Comment: how to access in json parsing can you describe?

Comment: @Johnson `var jsObject = JSON.parse(jsonData);` At this point, the variable `jsObject` can be accessed normally.

Comment: here is my question can you check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27424584/how-to-use-multiple-values-in-single-key-in-json-parsing?noredirect=1#comment43299243_27424584

Comment: @Johnson Sorry mate, but it doesn't look like your problem is JavaScript specific, so I can't help you.

Answer (score 10):

```
{
  "number" : ["1","2","3"],
  "alphabet" : ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```

Answer (score -9):

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "BLR": {
            "origin": "JAI",
            "destination": "BLR",
            "price": 127,
            "transfers": 0,
            "airline": "LB",
            "flight_number": 655,
            "departure_at": "2017-06-03T18:20:00Z",
            "return_at": "2017-06-07T08:30:00Z",
            "expires_at": "2017-03-05T08:40:31Z"
        }
    }
};
```