# Flask JSON output as multiple values with single key

Tags: python, json

I am working on Flask app where I need to return list as response, how I can output as key with multiple values.

[Like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093180/store-multiple-values-in-single-key-in-json)

```
    a = [1,2,3]    
    return jsonify({ 'List': a })
    
    
    Output 
    {
         "Lsit":[1,2,3]
    }
```

How do i get

```
    {
        "List": ["1", "2", "3"],
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just use `map()`?

```
jsonify{'List': list(map(str,a))}
```

Answer (score 2):

use map to change every number to string.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
return jsonify({ 'List': list(map(str, a)) })
```